# How to load string Array or string list records from database using Contains in c#

Tags: c#

I have records in database with 1stChoice 2ndChoice & 3rdChoice.I have one field called string choice in database.whenever I change the choice of any records to the above choice, I will save it in the string in database.I have 3 checkbox. whenever client select any of choice or multiple choices, I want to fetch the records according to the client selection.
I have the selected value in model.ChoiceCategory in comma separated form.Am i doing it in right way ?..Please suggest me to load multiple choices data from database

```
List<string> choicecategory = model.ChoiceCategory.Split(',').ToList();

q = q.Where(x => x.choice.Contains(choicecategory) ||    x.choice.Contains(choicecategory) || x.choice.Contains(choicecategory)).ToList();
```

But unable to get output.Suggest me the proper way to load all records according to choice selection..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if your choice is in choicecategory you should do it the other way around :

```
q = q.Where(x => choicecategory.Contains(x.choice).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this.but it is loading only records of 1st choice,but I am selecting multiple checkboxes.it only loading 1st choice records

Comment: Thanks you have suggested me 70% answer.doesn't need to split the string.directly model.ChoiceCategory.Contains(x.Choice).toList(); is working..Thanks